# flask-socketio has no attribute 'on'

Tags: python, flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I keep getting this error with my code:
AttributeError: module 'socketio' has no attribute 'on'

I have uninstalled and reinstalled flask-socketio and it doesn't help. I have also tried python-socketio and python engineio with the same errors.
Here is my file structure:

```
micro/
  env/
  app/
    __init__.py
    main/
      __init.py__
      routes.py
```

For reference here is where socketio pulls from whether I do "import socketio" or "from flask_socketio import socketio"

```
<module 'socketio' from 'C:\\Users\\jonat\\facti\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\socketio\\__init__.py'>
```

This is my routes.py code:

```
from flask_socketio import emit, join_room, leave_room, socketio

#this is the first on attribute that causes the crash.
@socketio.on('joined', namespace='/chat')
def joined(message):
    print('joined')
    """Sent by clients when they enter a room.
    A status message is broadcast to all people in the room."""
    room = session.get('room')
    join_room(room)
    emit('status', {'msg': session.get('name') + ' has entered the room.'}, room=room)
```

Here is the app **init**.py

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
socketio = SocketIO()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)    

    socketio.init_app(app)
```

Here is my pip freeze:

```
(env) PS C:\Users\jonat\facti> pip freeze
alembic==1.7.6
Babel==2.9.1
bidict==0.22.0
blinker==1.4
certifi==2021.10.8
cffi==1.15.0
chardet==4.0.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.11
click==8.0.3
colorama==0.4.4
cryptography==36.0.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
Deprecated==1.2.13
dnspython==2.2.0
docutils==0.18.1
dominate==2.6.0
elasticsearch==7.17.0
email-validator==1.1.3
Flask==2.0.2
Flask-Babel==2.0.0
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Flask-HTTPAuth==4.5.0
Flask-Login==0.5.0
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Migrate==3.1.0
Flask-Moment==1.0.2
Flask-SocketIO==5.1.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
Flask-WTF==1.0.0
gevent==21.12.0
greenlet==1.1.2
guess-language-spirit==0.5.3
gunicorn==20.1.0
httpie==3.0.2
idna==3.3
importlib-metadata==4.10.1
importlib-resources==5.4.0
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.3
lmtpd==6.2.0
lockfile==0.12.2
Mako==1.1.6
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
multidict==6.0.2
numpy==1.22.2
onetimepass==1.0.1
packaging==21.3
Pillow==9.0.1
pycparser==2.21
Pygments==2.11.2
PyJWT==2.3.0
pyOpenSSL==22.0.0
pyparsing==3.0.7
PyQRCode==1.2.1
PySocks==1.7.1
python-daemon==2.3.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.19.2
python-editor==1.0.4
python-engineio==4.3.1
python-socketio==5.5.2
pytz==2021.3
redis==4.1.2
requests==2.27.1
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
rq==1.10.1
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.31
stripe==2.65.0
typing_extensions==4.0.1
urllib3==1.26.8
visitor==0.1.3
Werkzeug==2.0.2
wrapt==1.13.3
WTForms==3.0.1
zipp==3.7.0
zope.event==4.5.0
zope.interface==5.4.0
```

Comment: Does it work to import `socketio` from your '\_\_init\_\_' file instead of from `flask_socketio`?

Comment: I tried that with no luck. I did it in a python terminal and the flask init. For some reason socketio isn't loading it's on attribute.

Comment: Ok great. Then just to make sure, you have already tried `from app import socketio` in your routes.py file?

Comment: That's what it was. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by importing socketio from app. The code below shows how to initialize socketio and then import it properly with blueprints. [Miguel Grinberg explains it here.](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent) Thanks for the help everyone!

app **init.py**

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler, RotatingFileHandler
import os
from flask import Flask, request, current_app
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from config import Config

socketio = SocketIO()


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)
    socketio.init_app(app)
```

events.py

```
from threading import 
from app import db, socketio
from flask_socketio import emit, join_room, leave_room

@socketio.event
def my_event(message):
    session['receive_count'] = session.get('receive_count', 0) + 1
    emit('my_response',
         {'data': message['data'], 'count': session['receive_count']})
```

File structure for those curious:

```
micro/
  env/
  app/
    __init__.py
    main/
      __init.py__
      events.py
```